# 2.8. How to make properties tab horizontal instead of vertical, like in 2.79

Tags: interface

Is there a way to get the properties tab looking like the one from 2.79, where the options were put horizontally instead of vertically?

[image]

Instead of like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is correct so I'm making it a comment not an Answer.  But I have noticed that loading older files will (by default) load the UI details from the file, including disorienting things like having headers on the bottom.  If this strip is included in that, you can load an old file, then clear the contents, and then save that as your default.blend.

Comment: @JDługosz AFAIK the 2,8 properties navigation bar cannot be put into horizontal mode. It can be hidden and switched left / right.  In 2.7 and below it was possible to make the flow of the properties panel either vertical (default) or horizontal  (rt click in header)   If this is implemented in 2.8 then would assume navigation bar would be top / bottom.